# Does Android Managed profile encrypt SD card?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-managed-profile

I am using this intent to create an android managed profile using the intent ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE. It prompts me to encrypt my device. I am positive it doesn't encrypt the SD card. But I am not able to justify why it doesn't do it. Is there any official document supporting this?

Answer (score 0):

The encryption is the way that OS create the separation between storage spaces of the two profiles (Each profile can only decrypt their own space). Even if you have a SD Card inserted, **the managed profile will always be created in the device storage**. So there is no point in encrypting the SD card since it is not going to be used for the feature 'android-managed-profile'.